# How to Use Dynamic Dropdown Selected value in Php

Tags: php, html

Php/Html:
   Here I add The all Countries list to add/edit page.But Edit page Want Value Selected in dropdown.please help

```
<select class="form-control" id="country_list" name="country">
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $network_lists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM media_countries");
    foreach($network_lists as $network_list){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $network_list->country_name ?>" selected="<?php 
       echo $network_list->country_name ?>"><?php echo $network_list>country_name ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: What value holds the value which you want selected?

Comment: aren't you missing a ```}``` and  ```$network_list>country_name is wrong, it should be: ``` $network_list->country_name```

Comment: Its the Editing Time Mistake.sorry.

Comment: I want country_name .

Comment: Which variable holds value of selected country name?

Comment: $network_list->country_name

Comment: How to use Normal Dynamic Selected In Dropdown

Comment: @JohnBright its is the value of loop for all countries I am asking about value of stored country for editing

Comment: selected="<?php echo $network_list->country_name ?>" this must be selected ="TRUE"; try this it should work fine

Comment: Both Are Same. value="$network_list->country_name"

Comment: How could be both are same. selected country must hold different variable. so that comparison can be done

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.  This will check the value against the value the user selects with the value from the database and properly populate your dropdown menu.

```
global $wpdb;
$network_lists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM media_countries");

echo
'<select class="form-control" id="country_list" name="country">';

foreach($network_lists as $network_list) {

  if($_POST['country'] == $network_list->country_name) {

    echo  '<option value="' . $network_list->country_name . '"' . ' selected="selected"' . '>' . $network_list->country_name . '</option>';

  }else {

    echo  '<option value="' . $network_list->country_name . '">' .  $network_list->country_name . '</option>';

    }

}

echo
'</select>';
```

Comment: I want Code To Edit Page.

Comment: This is I thing Add Page Code.

Answer (score 0):

Selected value is in **$_POST['country']**;

**Try:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="country_list" name="country">
   <?php 
      global $wpdb;
      $network_lists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM media_countries");
       foreach($network_lists as $network_list){
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $network_list->country_name; ?>" <?php echo ( $_POST['country_name'] == $network_list->country_name ? 'selected' : '' ); ?>><?php echo $network_list>country_name; ?></option>

    <?php }?>
</select>
```

The above code automatically selects the option that has value equals to the submitted $_POST['country'] value.